# Paypal plugin API

Tags: paypal

I have a problem with paypal API, it does not work, no price or payment is being made. Here is the code. Do I miss any step here? I've tried with some online examples with no luck.

I have a problem with paypal API, it does not work, no price or payment is being made. Here is the code. Do I miss any step here? I've tried with some online examples with no luck.

```
class plgPaypal extends JPlugin {
public $checkPossible = true;
protected $_params;
protected $_cfg;

public function __construct()
{

}

public function pay($price, $cfg, $params)
{
    $return = new stdClass();
    $return->state = 0;
    $return->price = $price;

    $this->_params = $params;
    $this->_cfg = $cfg;

    $auth = $this->_authorize();


    $paypal_url = "api.sandbox.paypal.com";
    $paypal_url = "api.sandbox.paypal.com";

    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->intent = "sale";
    $data->payer = new stdClass();
    $data->payer->payment_method = "paypal";
    $data->transactions = array();
    $data->transactions[0] = new stdClass();
    $data->transactions[0]->amount = new stdClass();
    $data->transactions[0]->amount->total = 34;
    $data->transactions[0]->amount->currency = "USD";
    $data->transactions[0]->payment_options = new stdClass();
    $data->transactions[0]->payment_options->allowed_payment_method = "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE";
    $data->redirect_urls = new stdClass();
    $data->redirect_urls->return_url = $this->_cfg->returnUrl;
    $data->redirect_urls->cancel_url = $this->_cfg->cancelUrl;


    $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $auth->access_token;
    $paypal_url = "api.sandbox.paypal.com";

    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$paypal_url/v1/payments/payment");

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $authorization));
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Payage");      // 1.09
    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    $response = json_decode($response);
    if (!empty($response->links[1]->href)) {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $app->redirect($response->links[1]->href . '/execute');
        return;
    } else {
        exit;
    }

    return $return;
}

public function cURLcheckBasicFunctions()
{
    if (!function_exists("curl_init") &&
        !function_exists("curl_setopt") &&
        !function_exists("curl_exec") &&
        !function_exists("curl_close")
    ) return false;
    else return true;
}

private function _authorize()
{


    $paypal_url = "api.sandbox.paypal.com";
    $user = $this->_params->client;
    $secret = $this->_params->secret;


    $handle = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$paypal_url/v1/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $secret);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Accept-Language: en_US'));
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    if ($code != 200) {
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($handle);

    return $response;
}

public function paymentCheck($link)
{

    $auth = $this->_authorize();
    $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $auth->access_token;

    $handle = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/' . $link);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $authorization));


    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $code = curl_getinfo($handle);
    $response = json_decode($response);


    curl_close($handle);
    exit;

    return $response;
}}
```

Thanks